# The following dependencies were not resolvable. See your build.gradle file for details

Tags: android-studio

I am creating an app for my school and the first activity is just a screen that says welcome and stuff. Then there's a button that says Continue and when they click on it, it is supposed to take them to a log in screen and from there they can log in. So i right clicked on the folder main on android studio and selected new -> activity ->login activity i put in the info for the name and its package name and when i clicked finish that error appeared. The following dependencies were not resolvable. See your build.gradle file for details.
    - com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Google Repository from the SDK manager.